# Developing in C# on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, windows, exe, cross-compiling

I wonder if I can develop in C# on Linux to produce an application which runs under Windows without using .Net Core (= using standard .Net Framework)

Is it possible? What compiler should I use?

What solutions would you suggest for testing? I think of VM but there might be other solutions.

Comment: You're looking for Mono.

Comment: Do you mean GUI application or console one (or maybe a service)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, to some extent, it is possible using Mono. Mono supports WinForms: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/

See compatibility here: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/